# IOS Unkonw Crash during launch,No Crash Log,No report,How can I catch It?

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

I have met a strange problem,My iOS App have integrated Bugly to colllect crash log ,there was a crash during launch, But bugly cannot collect it.

After I saw device log ,there was nothing about the crash.

Also I install signal and exception handler,But all of these didn't work.
The crash have left nothing.

How can I catch the crash log?

Thanks.

Comment: add error code in question .

Comment: I'm so sorry about this ,because our manager told me about the crash,But there was no crash log ,I even don't konw where had cause the crash.All the crash collect tool didn't work,  How can I collect the crash log?

Answer (score 0):

Check your your **applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions** method in AppDelegate.

You have to return YES from this method as soon as possible otherwise the OS will kill the application if takes more time to launch.

Comment: Thanks,I did some init work in applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions method in AppDelegate. I used some third-party SDK,whick adviced to be initd in applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions.Shoud I move these works to a thread ? I have find a crash log in device log before a long time.which had loged an error code 0x8badf00d.I search web to find the definition ,I will try you advice,Thanks.

Comment: Yes move those initialisation to a thread or somewhere else where you want it... that will solves your problem i think.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to chase down crashes without logs. I usually create a copy of the project (checking out a new branch via git works well), and then I start deleting files and deleting code while trying to successfully launch the project. Once I have deleted pretty much everything, if it's still not working, then I create a new project from scratch and start copying and pasting code into the new project. Usually at some point during this process I have a revelation.

It's not an elegant solution, but it works. One time I deleted everything in my project and so I started a new project and when I copied the storyboard to the new project, then the new project started crashing. I opened up the storyboard in a text editor and found some weird code that somehow got corrupted..

Comment: Thanks,But the crash didn't appear every time ,It appears only in rare cases.Since I didn't find the recurrence method,I cannot find where cause the crash. Yet the crash report system didn't work.So I have no crash Log,That's why this problem is such hard.

Comment: Do you have any idea how often this crash occurring? Could it be an OS error, or something else you have no control over?

Comment: It crashs about 1 or 2 times per day，sometimes works well. I asked custom service of crash report system for help,They told me if the app was killed by iOS ( lack of resource),it seems like a crash, the crash report system would not report the crash.So I fix memory leak in the whole app.In these two days, It seems to work well,The manager didn't told me about the crash occurred. I don't know if the real crash reason had been resolved.